# Python Array Construct in Class

Tags: python, list, class, matrix

I have addition and subtraction done with my class. But when I try to do multiplication I'm having unnecessary outmost external array.

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.m = []
        self.m.extend(args)

m1 = Matrix([1,2],[3,4])
```

It works. But for the multiplication

```
empty = Matrix([[0 for row in range(col_matrix)] for col in range(row_self)])
```

I get `[[[0, 0], [0, 0]]]` rather than `[[0, 0], [0, 0]]`. What can I do?

Comment: Nope because you use an asterisk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** because of the `extend` itself: but because you use `*args` (with asterisk `*`). Indeed if you call:

```
Matrix([[0,0],[0,0]])
```

what will happen is that **`args` is a tuple `([[0,0],[0,0]],)`** (with one element). So you extend the tuple and thus `append` the single element of the tuple: you **`append([[0,0],[0,0]])`**.

What you probably want is to extend **all elements of `args` one-by-one**, so:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.m = []
        for argi in args:
            self.m.extend(argi)
```

In case you want to **accept only one parameter**, you can simplify the process into:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,data): # without asterisk
        self.m = []
        self.m.extend(data)
```

Or make it more elegant, like:

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.m = list(data)
```

Note that you make a **shallow copy**: you better make a **deep copy** since otherwise the rows will still be the same and thus modifications to the rows in one matrix will reflect on the other matrix. So:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.m = deepcopy(data)
```